# How to turn this SQL into a Laravel Query Builder query?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I have the following query in SQL that works perfectly but I can't get it to work in Laravel's query builder.  Here is the SQL:

**SQL**

```
select count(listings_queue.mls_listing_id) from listings_queue
INNER JOIN listings
ON `listings_queue`.`mls_listing_id` = `listings`.`mls_listing_id`
WHERE `listings`.`mls_id`=`listings_queue`.`mls_id`
AND `listings`.`city`=`listings_queue`.`city`
```

**Laravel Query Builder**

```
$count = DB::table('listings_queue')
->join('listings', function($join)
{
    $join->on('listings_queue.mls_listing_id', '=', 'listings.mls_listing_id');
})
->where('listings.mls_id','=','listings_queue.mls_id')
->where('listings.city', '=', 'listings_queue.city')
->count();
```

This produces a count of 0 yet the SQL above produces 11,550 rows.

If I do the Laravel Query Builder and use the toSql(); at the end, I get:

**toSql(); in Laravel**

```
select * from `listings_queue`
inner join `listings`
on `listings_queue`.`mls_listing_id` = `listings`.`mls_listing_id`
where `listings`.`mls_id` = ?
and `listings`.`city` = ?
```

The crazy thing here is that the raw SQL output looks the same other than the ? bindings.  Coudl that be the problem?  I don't understand why my query builder query running on the same database as the raw SQL at the top produces different results.

One other clue is that if I remove the where clause in my laravel query builder query, I get results.

I asked this question elsewhere but didn't do a good job explaining so here it is.  Thanks so much for any help you can provide!

Comment: I dont know 1% laravel but i can see it is expecting a object in the right or can be seen as a laravel bug.

Comment: I believe that's just binding.  No idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Closure like:

```
$count = DB::table('listings_queue')
->join('listings', 'listings_queue.mls_listing_id', '=', 'listings.mls_listing_id')
->where('listings.mls_id','=','listings_queue.mls_id')
->where('listings.city', '=', 'listings_queue.city')
->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this multiple condition of join

```
$count = \DB::table('listings_queue')
->select('listings_queue.*')
->distinct()
->join('listings', function ($join)
{
    $join->on('listings_queue.mls_listing_id', '=', 'listings.mls_listing_id')
    ->on('listings_queue.mls_id', '=', 'listings.mls_id')
    ->on('listings_queue.city', '=', 'listings.city');
})
->count();
```